# JPA inheritance and composite primary key extension

Tags: jpa

Say, I have two (or three) tables.

```
PLAYER_POINT
----------------------------------------
    PLAYER_ID | PK, FK -> PLAYER
    POINT_ID  | PK, FK -> POINT
    EARNED    | INT

PLAYER_POINT_YEAR
----------------------------------------
    PLAYER_ID | PK, FK -> PLAYER_POINT
    POINT_ID  | PK, FK -> PLAYER_POINT
    YEAR      | PK
    EARNED    | INT

PLAYER_POINT_MONTH
----------------------------------------
    PLAYER_ID | PK, FK -> PLAYER_POINT_YEAR
    POINT_ID  | PK, FK -> PLAYER_POINT_YEAR
    YEAR      | PK, FK -> PLAYER_POINT_YEAR
    MONTH     | PK
    EARNED    | INT
```

Is it possible with JPA to use `@Inheritance` with extending composite primary keyset?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JPA: is it possible to change the PKs in an inheritance hierarchy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744822/jpa-is-it-possible-to-change-the-pks-in-an-inheritance-hierarchy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PK is fixed for an inheritance tree. You can't do that with inheritance